# Chart section is empty

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js

I'm trying to add some charts to an angular project, but it's always shown empty

Component

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  Router
} from '@angular/router';
import {
  Chart
} from 'chart.js';

import * as _ from 'lodash';
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-venta-grafica',
  templateUrl: './venta-grafica.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./venta-grafica.component.css']
})
export class VentaGraficaComponent implements OnInit {

  chart: any = null;

  constructor(
    private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.chart = new Chart("canvas", {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: ['1', '2', '3'],
        datasets: [{
          label: 'test1',
          data: [10, 20, 30],
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)'
        }]
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas">{{ chart }}</canvas>
```

But still, I'm only getting a blank page

Any ideas? I was using this site examples
https://coursetro.com/posts/code/126/Let's-build-an-Angular-5-Chart.js-App---Tutorial

Update:
So, tried adding your suggestion, none worked, but I took a peek at the charts object and saw this

[image: chart object properties]

I'm seeing that the canvas and ctx properties are null, so, is the chart object not getting the element on which it will be rendered?

Comment: the tutorial has `<div *ngIf="chart">` around the canvas element, did you try that as well?

Comment: that's only to show the chart if the chart object of the component is not empty

Comment: Did you try it? I think the issue is that you need to call `chart.update()` after modifying the chart object, but if you have an *ngIf around it you wouldn't need to because the chart would have all the data it needs at the time it's rendered. It sounds like the chart is rendering before the data is set. See this documentation: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html

Comment: Added it, no luck, please see update

Comment: `chart.update()` did the trick. thanks!

Comment: Great! I'd appreciate it if you would accept the answer I posted below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `chart.update()` after initializing the chart object. See the documentation for modifying chart data here: chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html

Answer (score 0):

In the component you are using the chart, add this to the component's CSS:

```css
:host {
  display: block;
}
```

result: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mqsupm